# jquery hide elements from dropdown list

Tags: html, jquery, custom-data-attribute

i need to show the elements with attributes selected from dropdown list and hide all others

```
   <select id="date-selector">
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>



  <div class="test" data-number="7">Seven</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="7">Another Seven</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="7">Another Seven</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="7">Another Seven</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="8">Eight</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="8">Another Eight</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="9">Nine</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="9">Another Nine</div>
    <div class="test" data-number="9">Another Nine</div>
```

Now, If i select 7, all elements other than 7 must be hidden.

How do i do this using jquery hide() ?

Note: I have more than one element with same data attribute and I cannot hide all the elements with the class "test". I have to hide the elements whose attribute is not 7.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.test').hide();
$('[data-number=' + $('select').val() + ']').show();

$('select').on('change', function() {

  var value = $(this).val();
  $('.test').hide();
  $('[data-number=' + value + ']').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="date-selector">
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
</select>

<div class="test" data-number="7">Seven</div>
<div class="test" data-number="7">Another Seven</div>
<div class="test" data-number="7">Another Seven</div>
<div class="test" data-number="7">Another Seven</div>
<div class="test" data-number="8">Eight</div>
<div class="test" data-number="8">Another Eight</div>
<div class="test" data-number="9">Nine</div>
<div class="test" data-number="9">Another Nine</div>
<div class="test" data-number="9">Another Nine</div>
```

Comment: I have more than one element with same data attribute and I cannot hide all the elements with the class "test". I have to hide only elements whose attribute is not 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$( "#date-selector" ).change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();    
    $('.test[data-number!="'+value+'"]').hide();
    $('.test[data-number="'+value+'"]').show();
```

});

Please see solution in [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/543njL38/1/)

Comment: I have more than one element with same data attribute and I cannot hide all the elements with the class "test". I have to hide only elements whose attribute is not 7.

Comment: OK, You can try $('.test[data-number!="'+value+'"]').hide(); It may be suitable for what you need